# how to handle all exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, handle

Is there any **safe** way to handle all exceptions in a .net website using c# and asp?
I read a lot from different webistes and what  i found is to use one of  those:

1. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException Event
2. Application.ThreadException Event

   But a lot of people are arguing how safe is to handle all exceptions together(out of     memory,stackoverflow exception etc).
   I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: What do you mean by safe, and what do you want to do when you 'handle' them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at postsharp http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/exception

Answer (score 0):

This article might provide you with more information on global error handling within asp.net:

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/961301/Global-Exception-Handling-with-ASPNET.htm

Greetings